# I deleted /lib How can I get it back?

Tags: shared-libraries

I deleted /lib by accident. Now I can only (as far as I can tell) run `echo`, `cd`, and access my lighttpd server. How can I fix this? So far, I've just been able to poke around using cd and echo to find files.

Comment: In linux when you remove something, it is gone. (no "trash" or recycle bin if you ran a `rm` command). If you did a dele via a gui, the trash folder is found at: /home/username/.local/share/Trash depending on your OS (witch you didn't mention)

Comment: @Havnar I know, I was manually installing a program that adds files to /var/lib. When the library showed as unknown. I thought I might have copied /usr/lib to / (meaning /lib) so I did sudo rm /lib I now have a copy of raspbian which i will probably copy the lib folder from using ubuntu

Comment: you could try, and it might work but it's ill advised.

Comment: I mean the new raspbian -> old raspbian not ubuntu -> raspbian

Comment: I was aware of that. you still might get issues down the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily I am afraid. If you can afford downtime the easiest thing is to shutdown, backup the disk, reinstall then recover from the backup.

If you can afford downtime but don't want to do a complete reinstall you can backup the disk, get a copy of the original image and copy the /lib directory to your image. But the files in there will be out of date/incomplete but might be enough to boot your system. Once booted you should reinstall all installed packages to repopulate /lib with up to date files. This might not fix everything and you could end up having problems much further down the line.

You can also attempt to [recover the deleted files](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-ext3-ext4-deleted-files-recovery-howto.html) but this is complicated and less likley to work the longer your system is running after the files have been delete.

If you cannot afford downtime attempt to backup any important files. Then you may be lucky enough to be able to scp /lib from a the original image onto the running system and then reinstall all the packages to repopulate /lib - this is not without its risks however and you could end up taking down the system anyway. A safer approach might be to prepare a second disk first to minimise the downtime if something does go wrong.

You should still have access to any command that is still in memory, or that does not need /lib as well as bash builtin (like echo) - for this reason, if you have not already, it is best not to logout of the machine once you have realized the damage (better chance of more commands being in memory). This is also why your webserver is still running, it has already loaded everything it needed from /lib into memory and so continues to work. You might find that if you restart lighttpd, it will fail to come back up.

Mostly from this you sould learn a couple of lessons:

1. Make backups
2. Don't run things as root when you don't need to, avoid logging in as root.

Comment: Thanks, although this is not what I wanted to hear, it was the right answer.